What does ‘whosoever will’ mean in Revelation 22v17
Does ‘whosoever will’ simply mean ‘whosoever’ or does it mean ‘whosoever has a will to come' or of course something else, because I’m asking without knowing the answer myself.

Rev 22:17 - And the Spirit and the bride say, "Come!" And the one
hearing, let him say, "Come!" And the one thirsting let him come; the
one desiring, let him take freely the water of life.


Thank you for your answer .

Someone who is unwilling to come to this free supply of living water to quench their thirst obviously will not be included in the "whosoever".
Someone who is thrilled at the invitation to "come" will respond by coming and receiving this free, living water.
The Greek words used in Revelation can help deal with whether the individual coming is exercising their will in order to drink, or whether an 'outside' will is influencing them. Can the word 'will' be correctly understood as 'shall' - or, what?
In Revelation 17:17 the word 'gnome' is used, a word that means 'mind, judgment, decision'. The context is how the destruction of the vile woman sitting on the beast is suddenly destroyed:

"For God hath put in their hearts to fulfil his will, [literally, to
do the mind of God] and to agree, and give their kingdom unto the
beast, until the words of God shall be fulfilled." Revelation 17:17
K.J.V.

That word 'gnome' is not used in Revelation 22:17. It is 'thelo', which means 'to wish, to will, to mean'. (Young's Exhaustive Concordance used for both text instances.)
In the first text, God influences a desire in the heart of his enemies - to give their kingdom to the beast. Once that desire is roused in their hearts, then they make up their minds to do what their hearts now desire. Thereby, God's will [purpose] is carried out without them knowing their decision actually gets the mind of God carried out by their decision. Until it's too late, of course.
In the text in question, the desire of each individual to get their thirst quenched is already there. It is their heart-felt desire. And so their mind requires no influencing, or changing. Their mind is already in accord with the will of the Spirit and the Bride to accept their invitation. Thus, they willingly come.
Another way of putting this answer is to say that those whose hearts are in accord with the Spirit and the Bride do not need to have an outward influence on making their minds up to come. They will come, because their will is in harmony with the will of the Spirit and the Bride: they come freely, willingly!

Thank you for your answer .

The crucial matter is the thirst. If one is happy with the world, content in the religion of the world, undisturbed by the presence of sin 'within one's members', without a conscience of past transgressions and oblivious of the immense subject of the righteousness of God and its implications, then one will not be 'athirst'.
And one will not come.
The question is, How is this thirst generated ? By the individual ? Or by Divine Providence and by Divine ministration and by Divine influence ?
The willingness is because of thirst.
Thirst is not hunger. Hunger can stay with me for days, weeks, unsatisfied and I am not greatly the worse.
Thirst I must satisfy immediately, within a day, or at most two.
It is urgent. Absolutely crucial.
That is the kind of prompting that causes the willingness.

Blessed are they that hunger and thirst after righteousness for they shall be filled [Matthew 5:6 KJV/TR]


Thank you for your answer .

Appreciated. Yours up-voted +1.

Note the progression in the four parts/sentences of Rev 22:17 -

And the Spirit and the bride say, "Come!" - The INVITATION
And the one hearing, let him say, "Come!" - ie, accept the invitation
And the one thirsting let him come; - allow the Spirit implant the desire to come
the one desiring, let him take freely the water of life.  That is, be saved eternally

The pivotal verb in Rev 22:17 is διψάω (dipsaó) = "I thirst", or, "I desire earnestly".  This verb occurs 16 times in the NT and when it is NOT used literally, ie, when it is used metaphorically, it always means to thirst for eternal life or righteousness.

Matt 5:6 - Blessed are those hungering and thirsting for righteousness, for they will be filled.
John 4:14 - But whoever drinks the water I give him will never thirst. Indeed, the water I give him will become in him a fount of water springing up to eternal life.”
John 6:35 - Jesus said to them, "I am the bread of life; the one coming to Me never shall hunger, and the one believing in Me never shall thirst at any time.
John 7:37 - Now in the last day of the feast, the great day, Jesus stood and cried out, saying, "If anyone thirsts, let him come to Me and drink.
Rev 7:16 - they will not hunger any more, neither will they thirst anymore, nor shall the sun at all fall upon them, nor any scorching heat;
Rev 21:6 - And He said to me, "It is done! I am the Alpha and the Omega, the beginning and the end. To the one thirsting I will give of the spring of the water of life freely.
Rev 22:17 - The Spirit and the bride say, “Come!” Let the one who hears say, “Come!” And let the one who is thirsty come, and the one who desires the water of life drink freely.

Now, we should recall what Paul says in Rom 3:10-18 -

... “There is no one righteous, not even one. There is no one who
understands, no one who seeks God. ...

Or, to use the metaphor at hand, no one who is "thirsty" for righteousness.  Salvation is the initiative of God and desires to know God come from God via the Spirit of God, John 16:8, 14:17, 15:26, Phil 2:13, John 6:44, Rom 2:4, 5:5-8 Eph 2:5, 1 John 4:19.
That is, "whoever will/desires" means two things:

salvation is a free gift of God's grace
the desire for salvation and the associated righteousness is implanted by God according as God the Father "draws him". John 6:44.

The ones to be lost resist this implanted desire to be with God. Acts 7:51, 1 Thess 5:19, Eph 4:30.

I was with you . . . . .  until that last sentence. The Grace I am aware of is 'irrestistible'.

Thank you for your answer Dottard ..  I will re-read it to take it in .. incidentally do you use special software that copies over Bible verses or do you go to the trouble of typing each verse by hand which I appreciate either way .. just wondering how it is done .

@NigelJ - do you have a Bible verse asserting "irrestistible grace".  I have provided three above where people are accused of resisting the Holy Spirit.

Therefore hath he mercy on whom he will have mercy, and whom he will he hardeneth. Romans 9:18. Those who resist do so because their hearts have been hardened. 'Lest they should be converted and I should heal them'. But of others . . . . Yea, I have loved thee with an everlasting love: therefore with lovingkindness have I drawn thee. Jeremiah 31.3. The word 'irrestistible' is my own word to describe what it actually feels like.

@NigelJ - then how do you explain Matt 23:27 - addressing the same people as Jer 31:3 which says, "... but you were unwilling".  How do you explain Acts 7:51, 1 Thess 5:19, Eph 4:30; or do these texts not matter/

I don't understand your point regarding those five texts. If some are able to resist grace and some are not able to resist grace then there is a definite difference between these two categories. And I understand (and believe) that the difference between them lies within God himself, and is not a matter of human will. But of the eternal purpose and will of the Father. That is my faith. And that is my own, personal, experience.

@NigelJ - then why did Jesus and the apostles rebuke them that resisted God's will if that was outside their control?  And, how do you know it was outside their control?  BTW, that is not my faith and not my experience.  My faith is based on the clear declarations of the Scriptures.

Ah, but the clay is not to complain to the potter, Why hast thou made me thus ? Who hath resisted his will ? For some vessels are for honour, made. And some for dishonour. What if God, willing to shew his wrath, and to make his power known, endured with much longsuffering the vessels of wrath fitted to destruction: and that he might make known the riches of his glory on the vessels of mercy, which he had afore prepared unto glory Romans 9:22.
